# Android Failure 5(database is locked) issue

Tags: android, sql

In my app need to cal several web service in async task and insert large data into different tables in a database with each response, for each table fast insertion iam locking the database by begin and end transactions. the problem is after all the web-services if i try to insert new record the log shows **Failure 5(database is locked)**. I have checked if the database is locked by inTransaction(), isDbLockedByOtherThreads and isDbLockedByCurrentThread. all returned false.

how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite does not allow concurrent writes and by default when a write is in progress, attempt to start another transaction will fail with this error. In the C API, there is a function to make it retry repeatedly with short sleeps between instead (`set_busy_timeout`) for specified time, but I don't see similar API in the Android Java wrapper, so you'll probably have to handle retrying on this error yourself.

Also make sure that you correctly either commit or rollback all transactions (without explicit transactions finish all statements) under all possible error conditions.

The `isDbLockedByOtherThreads` is returning `false` probably either because the other transaction finishes before you call it or only start after you do or simply because it does not really know, since I am not aware of any function to do this check on the C level.

There is also similar error that happens if you want to modify a table and have an unfinished statement referring to it, but that is status 6 (table is locked).

Comment: i am writing and reading data with two different threads at the same time, do you think this is the reason for database lock. Specially I am using joints for gathering data from different tables.

Comment: @Kishore: Yes, that is definitely reason for database lock. Unless the database is in [WAL](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) mode, **no reading is permitted while write is in progress** (except from within the transaction). I am not sure Android builds support WAL mode; you can try [enabling it](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) and see. That will allow reading while write transaction is in progress (except during the checkpoint operation), but still only one writer at a time is allowed.